# make the webpage composition working on every window size css

Tags: css, button, center, margin

i would like to put the button into the middle of the height of the page

i tried this :

top: 50%;

but it doesnot work i found here that have to push top margin

i found a code : margin-top: -300px;

can i use something like margin-top : -width:50% this would mean that the button will be in the middle , how can i code it ?

how to 100% center it , and then put the button under that so the firt will be 50% and the second 60% even if i resize the window

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this by positioning it absolute in its parent element and then you can center the button by translating it.

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <button>Centered button</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; //50% from top
    left: 50%; //50% from left

    //translate it so 50% from the width and heigth of the button will be subtracted thus centering the button 
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Working js fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/u72bb8w9/1/). Don't forget to add vendor prefixes!

Another option would be flexbox. You can find more information about flexbox centering [here](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/).